# Почему неправильно выводится контент в скрипте?

Tags: html, jquery, css

При нажатии на надпись "70 каналов" и стрелку необходимо чтобы появлялся контент "показать контент"
https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/XaRzRR

```js
(function($) {
  $(".accordion > .arrow").addClass("active").next().slideDown();

  $(".accordion .arrow").click(function(j) {
    var dropDown = $(this).closest(".package__wrapper").find(".channel__menu");

    $(this).closest(".accordion").find(".channel__menu").not(dropDown).slideUp();

    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    } else {
      $(this).closest(".accordion").find("a.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    }

    dropDown.stop(false, true).slideToggle();

    j.preventDefault();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. Добавить для пункта меню "70 каналов"

`<div class="package__subitem col-sm-3 text-center">`

класс `submenu` чтобы получилось вот так:

`<div class="package__subitem col-sm-3 text-center submenu">`

Далее заменить селектор `$(".accordion .arrow").click(function(j) {`

на вот этот `$(".accordion .submenu").click(function(j) {`

Т. е. мы добавили для пункта меню с выпадающим контентом новый класс и в JS заменили селектор. Теперь при клике на текст или на иконку-стрелку будет показываться контент.